# What does /*i*/ syntax in SQL INSERT INTO Java String do

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I need to modify some legacy code for a web application. The previous author has used various SQL queries for some basic CRUD operations in a Java application

Anyways, I am encountering statements like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO DB.PERSON (PERSON_ID /*0*/, USER_ID /*1*/, EMP_ID /*2*/, "
  + " IN_DBX_FLAG /*3*/, FIRST_NAME /*4*/, MIDDLE_NAME /*5*/, LAST_NAME /*6*/)"
  + " VALUES (PERSON_S1.nextval ,/*1 USER_ID*/ ?, /*2 EMP_ID*/ ?, /*3 IN_DBX_FLAG*/ ?, "
  + " /*4 FIRST_NAME*/ ?,  "
  + " /*5 MIDDLE_NAME*/ ?, /*6 LAST_NAME*/ ?)";
```

I am not quite sure exactly what the indices `/*i*/` mean. I believe they are used for preventing SQL injections. I also thought it may have been the column index, but this appears to be incorrect, since the indices do not always match up with the column indices. The code goes on to assign values like so:

```
createStatement.setString(1, myDto.getUserId());
createStatement.setInt(2, myDto.getEmpId());
createStatement.setString(3, myDto.isInDBXFlag());
createStatement.setString(4, myDto.getFirstName());
createStatement.setString(5, myDto.getMiddleName());
createStatement.setString(6, myDto.getLastName());
```

I searched for this and could not find anything that explicitly references this '/*i*/' syntax.

Comment: They are comments to 'name' the unnamed parameters in the shown code. Although I've never seen this myself; is it an Oracle feature or are the (non-standard SQL) comments stripped elsewhere? (The SQL injection is prevented by the use of the prepared statement and the '?' placeholders; nothing more, nothing less.)

Comment: Those are comments and server no purpose. My guess is the author added them to keep track of the index to column mapping in the PreparedStatement (so you don't have to count all `?` to get the correct index number for the `setXXX()` calls.

Comment: Those are purely comments.  I assume the original developer added them to help him (or her) keep track of the various parameters that needed to be passed.  They mean nothing to Oracle or to Java.